# Hibernate & MySql empty data

Tags: mysql, hibernate, mysql-workbench, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to make an interface for my database created in MySQL Workbench, and i can't simply view the data from any table. I can add a client, and then it appears on Workbench, but not in .jsp file. What am i missing ?

[image]

*pojo.Clienti*

```
    package pojo;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Clienti  implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer idclient;
    private String nume_institutie_firma;
    private String cod_unic;
    private String adresa;
    private Set angajats = new HashSet(0);

    public Clienti() {
    }

    public Clienti(String nume_institutie_firma, String cod_unic, String adresa, Set angajats) {
        this.nume_institutie_firma = nume_institutie_firma;
        this.cod_unic = cod_unic;
        this.adresa = adresa;
        this.angajats = angajats;
    }

    public Integer getIdclient() {
        return this.idclient;
    }

    public void setIdclient(Integer idclient) {
        this.idclient = idclient;
    }
    public String getnume_institutie_firma() {
        return this.nume_institutie_firma;
    }

    public void setnume_institutie_firma(String nume_institutie_firma) {
        this.nume_institutie_firma = nume_institutie_firma;
    }
    public String getcod_unic() {
        return this.cod_unic;
    }

    public void setcod_unic(String cod_unic) {
        this.cod_unic = cod_unic;
    }
    public String getAdresa() {
        return this.adresa;
    }

    public void setAdresa(String adresa) {
        this.adresa = adresa;
    }
    public Set getAngajats() {
        return this.angajats;
    }

    public void setAngajats(Set angajats) {
        this.angajats = angajats;
    }
}
```

*pojo.Clienti.hbm.xml*

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-mapping>
        <class name="pojo.Clienti" table="clienti" catalog="tema"
            optimistic-lock="version">
            <id name="idclient" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="idclient" />
                <generator class="identity" />
            </id>
            <property name="nume_institutie_firma" type="string">
                <column name="nume_institutie_firma" length="45" />
            </property>
            <property name="cod_unic" type="string">
                <column name="cod_unic" length="45" />
            </property>
            <property name="adresa" type="string">
                <column name="adresa" length="45" />
            </property>
            <set name="angajats" table="angajati" inverse="true"
                lazy="true" fetch="select">
                <key>
                    <column name="idclient" />
                </key>
                <one-to-many class="pojo.Angajati" />
            </set>
        </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>

*hibernate.cfg.xml*
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.internal.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tema</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">pass</property>
    <mapping resource="pojo/Angajati.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="pojo/Clienti.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="pojo/Proiecte.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

*hibernate.reveng.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <schema-selection match-catalog="tema"/>
  <table-filter match-name="proiecte"/>
  <table-filter match-name="clienti"/>
  <table-filter match-name="angajati"/>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

*web.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ClientiController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Controller.ClientiController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ProiecteController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Controller.ProiecteController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>AngajatiController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Controller.AngajatiController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ClientiController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ClientiController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ProiecteController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ProiecteController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>AngajatiController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/AngajatiController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

DAO.ClientiDao

```
      /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DAO;

import java.util.List;
import pojo.Clienti;

/**
 *
 * @author vali
 */
public interface ClientiDao {
    public void adaugaClienti (Clienti client);
    public List<Clienti> afiseazaClienti();
    public void modificaClienti (int idclient, String nume_institutie_firma, String cod_unic, String adresa);
    public void stergeClient (Clienti client);
}
```

*DAOImpl.ClientiDaoImpl*

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package DAOImpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import pojo.Clienti;
import DAO.ClientiDao;

/**
 *
 * @author vali
 */
public class ClientiDaoImpl implements ClientiDao{

    public void adaugaClienti(Clienti client) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(client);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public List<Clienti> afiseazaClienti() {
        List<Clienti> listaClienti = new ArrayList();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("From Clienti");
        listaClienti = query.list();
        return listaClienti;
    }

    public void modificaClienti(int idclient, String nume_institutie_firma, String cod_unic, String adresa) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        Clienti detaliiclienti = (Clienti) session.load(Clienti.class, idclient);
        detaliiclienti.setnume_institutie_firma(nume_institutie_firma);
        detaliiclienti.setcod_unic(cod_unic);
        detaliiclienti.setAdresa(adresa);
        session.update(detaliiclienti);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }

    public void stergeClient(Clienti client) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.delete(client);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

*Controller.ClientiController*

```
package Controller;

import DAO.ClientiDao;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import pojo.Clienti;
import DAOImpl.ClientiDaoImpl;

/**
 *
 * @author vali
 */
public class ClientiController extends HttpServlet {

    Clienti client = new Clienti();
    ClientiDaoImpl clientDaoImpl = new ClientiDaoImpl();

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getParameter("adaugaClient") != null) {
            String nume_institutie_firma = request.getParameter("nume_institutie_firma");
            String cod_unic = request.getParameter("cod_unic");
            String adresa = request.getParameter("adresa");
            client.setnume_institutie_firma(nume_institutie_firma);
            client.setcod_unic(cod_unic);
            client.setAdresa(adresa);
            clientDaoImpl.adaugaClienti(client);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("adauga_Client.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getParameter("afiseazaClienti") != null) {
            List<Clienti> listaClienti = new ArrayList();
            listaClienti = clientDaoImpl.afiseazaClienti();
            request.setAttribute("listaClienti", listaClienti);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("tabela_Clienti.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }

        if (request.getParameter("modificaClient") != null) {
            int id1 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idclient"));
            String nume_institutie_firma = request.getParameter("nume_institutie_firma");
            String cod_unic = request.getParameter("cod_unic");
            String adresa = request.getParameter("adresa");
            clientDaoImpl.modificaClienti(id1, nume_institutie_firma, cod_unic, adresa);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("adauga_Client.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        }

        if (request.getParameter("stergeClient") != null) {
            int id2 = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idclient"));
            client.setIdclient(id2);
            clientDaoImpl.stergeClient(client);
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("adauga_Client.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>
}
```

Comment: put log or debug this line listaClienti = clientDaoImpl.afiseazaClienti(); let's see if you are getting any result or not and alos check jsp there right variable is getting used or not.